# How to create this shadow effect?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create similar to [this shadow effects](https://www.jossandmain.com/), and inspected CSS in chrome, still i am not getting what i want, my current code is:

```
.imageShadow {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #bbb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #bbb;
    height: 293px;
}
```

Note: My image height is 293px

Is this will work in all browsers?

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the nice, curvy dropshadow then CSS at the current state does not allow it. They haven't used CSS to do this, they used [image sprites](https://secure.common.josscdn.com/st4/stores/common/jossandmain/sprites/sprite_jm_shadow_v1.png).

Answer (score -2):

Here is a chart that shows compatibility for css box-shadow:

http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

IE 9+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, and Chrome all support the style.

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: That wasn't his real question. He was asking how to create the shadow effect used on the site he linked to with CSS - the question about browser compatibility was a supplementary question.

Comment: Yeah, I get the distinction now. Discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166962/210746